# Creating Textured Paints Java

Tags: java, textures, paint, polygon

Creating a sort of strategy game, like a very basic version of civ 5. The map is created by tesselating hexagons so the command I'm using to colour them is g2d.fillPolygon(). What I'm wondering is if I could get some kind of roughed up (multiple colours mixed through) Paint to paint with so as to mimic a grassy pattern.

Don't quite know how to phrase it so let me know if you need extra clarification.

Thanks,

Comment: There appears to be a `TexturePaint` class [right in the docs.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TexturePaint.html)

Comment: Well... That kinda hurts :/ Was looking up rough not textured, exactly what I wanted though thanks.